# Issue changing javascript function based on media query with event handler

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, navigation, media-queries

Sorry if this is a basic question. I mainly work with design and am not entirely comfortable with JavaScript.

I have a navigation menu which is prompted to display when clicking an SVG using an Event Listener. Based on the size of the screen on which the menu is being displayed I would like to change the function to a function stating a different height for the navigation on click. This way smaller devices will have a certain height navigation, and larger will have a different height as well.

Here is the code as far as I have dabbled into it

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
mq.addListener(WidthChange);
WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
if (mq.matches) {
// at least 500px
document.getElementById("onclick").addEventListener("click", menuSize);

 function menuSize() {
document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.height = "35%";
document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById("movbilenav").style.opacity = "0";

}

} else {
// less than 500px
document.getElementById("onclick").addEventListener("click", menusizeL);

 function menusizeL() {
document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.height = "50%";
document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById("movbilenav").style.opacity = "0";

}
}

}
```

As of now I get no response at all when clicking the navigation menu. Thank you, and sorry if this is a rudimentary question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert your solution to mainly use css. Generally, the more you can solve with css instead of js, the more the browser will take care of everything and keep everything smooth.

You can just add a media query in your stylesheets to handle the height differences. To hide/show your menu, I'd rely on just adding a class via your js. Sample stylesheet:

```
#mobilemenu {
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
}
#mobilmenu.showing {
    opacity: 1;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #mobilemenu {
        height: 35%;
    }
}
```

Then you can just add your class via js:

```
document.getElementById('menuopener').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('mobilemenu').classList.toggle('showing');
});
```